# Having a missing keyword error when using Full outer join and Union All

Tags: oracle, union-all

I have my script to create 3 views and combine them with Full outer join and Union All queries. But when I run this query, I got a missing keyword error; The individual views are working OK with each select statement.

What is wrong with my queries?

---

```
CREATE OR replace force VIEW "VW_RANGE_REPORT_Jul2023"

WITH    live_str AS (        SELECT ------- from ---------- ),
        pend_str AS     (     SELECT  ----------from -----------),
        pend_only AS ( Select      --------from ---------)

SELECT  
NVL(lp.StoreNumber,pp.StoreNumber) AS StoreNumber, 
NVL(lp.StoreName,pp.StoreName) AS StoreName, 
lp.floorplanDBkey AS LiveFLRkey, 
lp.floorplanName As LiveFloorplanName, 
lp.FLRPENDDATE As LiveFLRPendDate, 
lp.FLRLIVEDATE AS LiveFLRLiveDate, 
lp.PlanogramKey AS LivePOGKey, 
lp.PlanogramName AS LivePOGName, 
lp.PlanogramPendingDate AS LivePOGPendDate, 
lp.PlanogramLiveDate AS LivePOGLiveDate, 
pp.floorplanDBkey AS PendFLkey, 
pp.floorplanName As PendFloorplanName, 
pp.FLRPENDDATE As PendFLRPendDate, 
pp.FLRLIVEDATE AS PendFLRLiveDate, 
pp.PlanogramKey AS PendPOGKey, 
pp.PlanogramName AS PendPOGName, 
pp.PlanogramPendingDate AS PendPOGPendDate, 
pp.PlanogramLiveDate AS PendPOGLiveDate

FROM    live_str lp

FULL OUTER JOIN pend_str pp ON pp.PlanogramVersionKey = lp.PlanogramVersionKey 
        AND pp.floorplanversionkey = lp.floorplanversionkey         
        AND pp.StoreNumber = lp.StoreNumber
        And pp.StorrDBKEy=lp.storedbkey

UNION ALL
    SELECT  po.StoreNumber,
            po.StoreName,
           NULL AS LiveFLRKey,
           NULL AS LiveFloorplanName,
           NULL AS LiveFLRPendDate,
            NULL AS LiveFLRLiveDate,
            NULL AS LivePOGKey,
            NULL AS LivePOGName,
            NULL AS LivePOGPendDate,
            NULL AS LivePOGLiveDate,
                 po.FloorplanDBKey AS PendFLKey,
                  po.FloorplanName as PendFloorplanName,
                  po.FLRPENDDATE as PendFLRPendDate,
                  po.FLRLIVEDATE as PendFLRLiveDate,
                  po.PlanogramKey AS PendPOGKey,
                po.PlanogramName AS PendPOGName,
            po.PlanogramPendingDate AS PendPOGPendDate,
            po.PlanogramLiveDate AS PendPOGLiveDate
FROM    pend_only po
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously wrong; I have no idea what you meant to do with this piece of code:

```
WITH    live_str AS (        SELECT ------- from ---------- ),
        pend_str AS     (     SELECT  ----------from -----------),
        pend_only AS ( Select      --------from ---------)
```

---

Perhaps you wanted to do something like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "VW_RANGE_REPORT_Jul2023"
AS
   WITH
      live_str
      AS
         (SELECT NVL (lp.storenumber, pp.storenumber) AS storenumber,
                 NVL (lp.storename, pp.storename) AS storename,
                 lp.floorplandbkey AS liveflrkey,
                 lp.floorplanname AS livefloorplanname,
                 lp.flrpenddate AS liveflrpenddate,
                 lp.flrlivedate AS liveflrlivedate,
                 lp.planogramkey AS livepogkey,
                 lp.planogramname AS livepogname,
                 lp.planogrampendingdate AS livepogpenddate,
                 lp.planogramlivedate AS livepoglivedate,
                 pp.floorplandbkey AS pendflkey,
                 pp.floorplanname AS pendfloorplanname,
                 pp.flrpenddate AS pendflrpenddate,
                 pp.flrlivedate AS pendflrlivedate,
                 pp.planogramkey AS pendpogkey,
                 pp.planogramname AS pendpogname,
                 pp.planogrampendingdate AS pendpogpenddate,
                 pp.planogramlivedate AS pendpoglivedate
            FROM live_str  lp
                 FULL OUTER JOIN pend_str pp
                    ON     pp.planogramversionkey = lp.planogramversionkey
                       AND pp.floorplanversionkey = lp.floorplanversionkey
                       AND pp.storenumber = lp.storenumber
                       AND pp.storrdbkey = lp.storedbkey
          UNION ALL
          SELECT po.storenumber,
                 po.storename,
                 NULL AS liveflrkey,
                 NULL AS livefloorplanname,
                 NULL AS liveflrpenddate,
                 NULL AS liveflrlivedate,
                 NULL AS livepogkey,
                 NULL AS livepogname,
                 NULL AS livepogpenddate,
                 NULL AS livepoglivedate,
                 po.floorplandbkey AS pendflkey,
                 po.floorplanname AS pendfloorplanname,
                 po.flrpenddate AS pendflrpenddate,
                 po.flrlivedate AS pendflrlivedate,
                 po.planogramkey AS pendpogkey,
                 po.planogramname AS pendpogname,
                 po.planogrampendingdate AS pendpogpenddate,
                 po.planogramlivedate AS pendpoglivedate
            FROM pend_only po)
   SELECT *
     FROM live_str;
```

Also, are you **sure** you want to enclose view name into double quotes and use mixed letter case in its name? You'll have to reference it that way - using double quotes and match letter case - EVERY TIME you use it. If I were you, I'd just

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW vw_range_report_jul2023
```

Comment: The OP's opening paragraph explains those opening lines in the query. The OP deliberately does not include them because they state that "The individual views are working OK with each select statement." You have to trust the OP that that part of the query is not relevant to the problem and their question relates to the unredacted part of the query.

Comment: Aha. If that's so, then it is `AS` that's missing at the end of the 1st line.